# How to filter elements of array based on id in Ionic2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am developing a mobile app using Ionic2. The intent is to dynamically insert people in the homepage. Whenever we click a person, a list of dynamically added items that are correlated only to that person (with an ID) should show up. I am not able to filter the items for each person, how can I filter the items only to the specific person ID?

This is the home where I add new people entries:

```
  public people:{personName:string, personID:string}[] = [];

  //will load all the people in the array
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    //addPersons is constructed from addPersonsService
    this.people = this.addPersons.getPeople();
  }

  //from the HTML, it will parse the personID from the array
  //it will redirect to the list of items for the specific person
  viewDebts(personID:string){  

    this.navCtrl.push(DebtsListPage, personID);

  }
```

This is addPersonsService

```
public people: {personName:string, personID:string}[] = [];

//this is called upon click from the HTML
addPerson(person:{personName:string, personID:string}  ){
    this.people.push(person);
}

getPeople(){   
    return this.people.slice();
}

generateID(id:string){
    return id;

}
```

In here I am displaying the items for each person

```
  debtValue:{personDebt:string, personId:string}[] = [];

  //this is where the list of items will be displayed
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    var id = this.navParams; //getting the id from the previous page
    this.debtValue = this.debts.getPersonsDebt(id); //debts comes from DisplayDebtsService
  } 

  //adding the item
  addDebts(debt:{personDebt:string, personId:string}) {
    this.debts.addDebt(debt);

  }
```

and finally this is DisplayDebtsService

```
  public debt:{personDebt:string, personId:string}[] = [];


  addDebt(debt:{personDebt:string, personId:string}){
      this.debt.push(debt);
  }

  getPersonsDebt(id:any){
      //this is where I am struggling. How do I filter the results based on the id of the person?
        return this.debt;
  }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Have you simply try with `.find()`? .. or `.filter()` ..

but here I think find() is better cause you're filter for ID ..which looks like  a PK key .. so you aspect only ONE person returning from your method and not more (like filter() do )

something like:

```
getPersonsDebt(id:any){
      //this is where I am struggling. How do I filter the results based on the id of the person?
        return this.debt.find(p=> p.id === id);
  }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: thanks for your help. I am doing as you told, but now I am facing another issue: whenever I call getPersonDebt with id, I get this error:  Type '{ personDebt: string; personId: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ personDebt: string; personId: string; }[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type '{ personDebt: string; personId: string; }'.
(property) DebtsListPage.debtValue: {
    personDebt: string;
    personId: string;
}[]

Comment: mmm it looks like it aspect an array as reposnse and not a object .. so try with filter .. like getPersonsDebt(id:any){
      //this is where I am struggling. How do I filter the results based on the id of the person?
        return this.debt.filter(p=> p.id === id);
  }

Comment: The error has disappeared now, thanks it's very useful. Would you mind explaining me why that made a difference? Problem now is that it won't print it on the screen at all after I insert a value. My guess is something to do with the way I am getting the data from the array